# data caching issue in ipython notebook

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science

In ipython notebooks, have imported dataset and stored in customer_df but, after some time have deleted it and saved the notebook. again, have imported the same dataset and stored it in customerData variable, and saved the notebook. but, In the notebook still it showing the old variable.please check/click this image for more details
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOgiw.png)

have followed the below thread:

[Ipython notebook caching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353600/ipython-notebook-caching-issue)

but still facing the same issue, please let me know your ideas to solve the issue?

Comment: Please provide your code as formatted (language-formatted) text instead of image. Images are not (easily) searchable and they may vanish in the future

Comment: yes, but I don't have a problem with code, have attached image for reference.plz check it